# Can't deploy because folder was not inside a directory whose name ends .war. (JBoss)

Tags: java, jboss, eclipse, maven

I created a default JSF Project using Maven2Eclipse.

When I try to start the home.xhtml JBoss returns the following error Message:

```
    (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015010: The deployment scanner found a directory named META-INF that was not inside a directory whose name ends with .ear, .jar, .rar, .sar or .war.
This is likely the result of unzipping an archive directly inside the C:\Users\Foo\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments directory, which is a user error.
The META-INF directory will not be scanned for deployments, but it is possible that the scanner mayfind other files from the unzipped archive and attempt to deploy them, leading to errors.

09:43:57,387 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] 
(DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015010: The deployment scanner found a directory named WEB-INF that was not inside a directory whose name ends with .ear, .jar, .rar, .sar or .war. 
This is likely the result of unzipping an archive directly inside the C:\Users\Foo\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\standalone\deployments directory, which is a user error. 
The WEB-INF directory will not be scanned for deployments, but it is possible that the scanner mayfind other files from the unzipped archive and attempt to deploy them, leading to errors.
```

I tried to replace my edit my standalone.xml with this

```
<deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir"
   path="deployments" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="false"/>
```

The messsge still appears.

I don't have this problem when I deploy a simple html project.